# JavaScript extend a class while using WeakMap for private variables

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-modules, es6-class, weakmap

I wrote some classes that have private variables through the use of `WeakMap()`. I did this by placing a `WeakMap` at the top of the class file.

**light.js**

```
let privateVars = new WeakMap();

class Light {
  constructor(state, brightness) {
    let info = {"state": state, "brightness": brightness, "createdAt": Date.now()};
    // Save info into privateVars
    privateVars.set(this, info);
  }

  switch() {
    let info = privateVars.get(this);
    info.state = !info.state;
    privateVars.set(this, info);
  }
}
```

This worked fine, I was able to add some getters and setters, which had validation and type-checking.

Now I'm wanting to extend that class to another class but I'm having trouble sharing the private property information between the child and parent class files.

**flashingLight.js**

```
let privateVars = new WeakMap();
let flashing;

import Light from './light.js';

class FlashingLight extends Light {

  constructor(state=false, brightness=100, flashMode=true) {
    super(state, brightness);
    let info = {"state": state, "brightness": brightness, flashMode: flashMode, "createdAt": Date.now()};
    privateVars.set(this, info);
    if(flashMode===true) {
      this.startFlashing();
    }
  }

  startFlashing() {
    flashing = setInterval(this.lightSwitch,5000);
  }

}
```

When `this.lightSwitch` is called from the `setInterval` function inside `startFlashing` it can't access the state of the object.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined
    at lightSwitch
```

Is this because these functions are spread out across the two files? Is there anyway around this so that I can use both private variables and class extensions?

Comment: It is because you have two different variables named `privateVars`, and each file use it own version.

Comment: @some I updated with the error I get. Given I have 2 variables named `privateVars` and have set both, shouldn't I at least get back 1 of those 2 values? Instead it returns undefined.

Comment: In classical inheritance patterns, subclasses do not have access to base class private variables anyway. Are you intending to implement _protected_ variables?

Comment: By the way, I see no implementation of `this.lightSwitch` anywhere.

Comment: Ah, the second problem is with setInterval, where you pass a function, and `this` will not be what you want. You can use  `setInterval(this.lightSwitch.bind(this),5000);`

Comment: @some thanks so much! Do you want to post as an answer or should I delete this?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts thanks for pointing that out. I should probably just pass `state` and `brightness` to `super()` and only worry about `flashMode` within my sub-class. If I need to use those variables in the sub-class I can use getter and setter methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of your problems is the usage of [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) where you pass a function. When that function is called, `this` is not what you expected. You can use [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to force it to be what you want, like `setInterval(this.lightSwitch.bind(this),5000)`